# Metric space locally compact but not uniformly locally connected

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, locally-connected

> **Definition:** A set $M$, also in a metric space, is said to be *uniformly locally
> connected* if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that any
> pair of points $x, y$ of $M$ with $d(x,y) < \delta$ lie together in a connected subset
> of $M$ of diameter less than $\varepsilon$.

I know that if a metric space is compact and locally connected then it is uniformly locally compact (See [A compact locally connected metric space is "uniformly locally connected"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2562393/a-compact-locally-connected-metric-space-is-uniformly-locally-connected) ) if instead of compactness we have local compactness, the result is true?. Intuitively I think not. Could you show me an example? thanks